# Rails - children of multiple parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have two models - `parent` and `child`, and parent has_many children, and I have an array of parents and want to retrieve all of the children for all of those parents, is there a way I can do this in Rails without writing the SQL statement manually?

This is what I want to do:

```
@parents = Parent.where("[various conditions]")
@children = @parents.children
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Child.where(:parent_id => @parents.pluck(:id))
```

or

```
@parent_ids = Parent.where("[various conditions]").pluck(:id)
Child.where(:parent_id => @parent_ids}
```

or u can use  join

```
Child.join(:parent).merge(Parent.where("[various conditions]")) #!!readonly
```